# HTML Connected dropdown (more than one)with number as value

Tags: javascript, html-select

Basically, I want to create more then 1, dropdowns, which contains numbers as value eg.

```
<select id="dp1">
<option value='op1'>1</option>
<option value='op2'>2</option>
<option value='op3'>3</option>
</select>

<select id="dp2">
<option value='op1'>1</option>
<option value='op2'>2</option>
<option value='op3'>3</option>
</select>

<select id="dp3">
<option value='op1'>1</option>
<option value='op2'>2</option>
<option value='op3'>3</option>
</select>
```

this is just one dropdown. lets say I have 3 dropdown lists with same numbers with different default value eg. dp1 -> 1, dp2 -> 2, dp3 -> 3 . So, Now if user changes value of `dp3 to 1` the value of other dropdown list should get change automatically as per sequence like `dp1 -> 2` and `dp2 -> 3`.

if i explain it with other example if user changes value of `dp3 to 2` the value `dp1 should not change` and value of `dp2 -> 3`should change.

How is it possible to do using Javascript / jquery. (I am using php to populate dropdown from database)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CqafY/1/ something like that?

Comment: what logic is the behind the changing of dropdownlists?what relationships are between them?

Answer (score 0):

If the data you're using is really just numeric, then something like this will work. [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/6p7E7/2/) for a jsfiddle example that demonstrates the behavior I think you're looking for.

```
<select id="dp1" class="dropdown"></select>
<select id="dp2" class="dropdown"></select>
<select id="dp3" class="dropdown"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">                     
var values = [1, 2, 3];

$(function() {
  initDropdowns();

  $('select.dropdown').change(function() {
    setDropdownValues($(this).attr('id'));                  
  });
}); 

function initDropdowns() {
  var optionsHtml = '';

  for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {              
    var value = values[i];
    optionsHtml += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>';
  }

  $('select.dropdown').append(optionsHtml);
    setDropdownValues();                
}

function setDropdownValues(excludeListId) {
  var valuesClone = values.slice();
  var $dropdowns = $('select.dropdown');

  if(excludeListId) {
    valuesClone.splice(Number($('#' + excludeListId).val()) - 1, 1);
  }             

  $('select.dropdown').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('id') !== excludeListId) {
      $(this).val(valuesClone[0]);
      valuesClone.splice(0, 1);
    }                   
  });   
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to change the previous dropdownlists buy changing the current dropdownlist maybe this sample code can help you :

```
$("select").change(function(){
    var selectValue = $(this).val();
    var toRemove = 'op';
    var value  = selectValue.replace(toRemove,'');
    var selectId = $(this).attr('id');
    var toRemove = 'dp';
    var id = selectId.replace(toRemove,'');
    id = id-1;
    for(var i = id; i>=1; i--){
         value = value -1;
         var newValue = "op"+value;
         $("#dp"+i).val(newValue);
      }
    });
```